# Typing is messy if I use html with QTextEdit

Tags: html, c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to change the attributes of single words such font and color. QTextEdit allows me to set the text as html via `setHtml(htmlText)`, after setting QString as html, typing becomes messy. I can't type spaces nor hit enter. Sometimes words are written backward.

```
void MainWindow::on_textEdit_textChanged()
{
    QString plainText = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QString htmlText = "<font color='red'>" + plainText + "</font>";

    disconnect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(on_textEdit_textChanged()));

    ui->textEdit->setHtml(htmlText);
    QTextCursor cursor(ui->textEdit->textCursor());
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::EndOfWord);
    ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);

    connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(on_textEdit_textChanged()));
}
```

The color is set correctly but typing is inconsistent. I'm not expert in html. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is a transfer representation for the syntax tree of the document. You need to be modifying one **or** the other, otherwise you'll face the fallout from interactions between the two. Choose one and stick to it.

Since you're using the `QTextDocument` interface, you should be making all changes using that interface. There's no need to deal with HTML directly then. To change attributes of a chunk of text, select the text, then manipulate it via the cursor API.